# Custom background on windows taskbar depending on the application

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I have a problem because due to having a lot of open applications in work I struggle with finding proper one one the taskbar. Many apps have their icons blue and it doesn't help to recognize which one is what.

I would love to have e.g. blue background under all Word windows, yellow under all Outlook and white under Firefox. This would help me to find the needed app immediately.

[image: That is an exemplary part of my taskbar]

Maybe you have your own solutions and proposals?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is technically possible.
You would certainly need third-party products for that.

I know of one application that helps organize the taskbar - 
[Bins](http://www.1upindustries.com/bins/),
which as its names suggests, organizes the icons by application as stacks/bins.

It used to be commercial at $5, but there is no longer any price mentioned on
its website.

[image]

Another option might be [Stardock's Groupy](https://www.stardock.com/products/groupy/)
(trialware, $9.99), which allows organizing applications into tabs,
which the documentation says has an option for Windows 8/10 where only the currently active tab is shown on the taskbar and other windows in the group are hidden from the taskbar. Switching tabs will switch which button is shown on the taskbar.

Comment: No exactly what I'm looking for, I wanted to have only background changed. Nevertheless thanks for help!